# Getting Gradients of Each Layer in Keras 2

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, keras-2

It's been days that I've been struggling just to simply view layers' gradients in the debug mode of Keras2. Needless to say, I have already tried codes such as:

```
import Keras.backend as K
gradients = K.gradients(model.output, model.input)
sess = tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.get_session()
evaluated_gradients = sess.run(gradients, feed_dict={model.input:images})
```

or

```
evaluated_gradients = sess.run(gradients, feed_dict{model.input.experimantal_ref():images})
```

or

```
with tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.get_default_graph())
```

or similar approaches using

> tf.compat.v1

which all lead to the following error:

> RuntimeError: The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the graph
>   before calling run().

I assume this should be the most basic tool any deep learning package could provide, it is strange why there seems no easy way to do so in Keras2. Any ideas?

Comment: You are mixing `keras` and `tf.keras`, that usually doesn't work. 
Choose one of the two and stick with it.

Comment: @DanielMöller but keras2 alone doesn't have set_session either and it won't allow me to see inside of tensors. How should I do so?

Comment: Then choose `tf.keras` instead of `keras`.

Comment: If you are looking into tensors with data (eager mode on), then you don't need to touch the sessions, just go with `tf.keras.gradients` directly. You can also try the gradient tape. There are examples of the tape in this custom training loop: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_training_walkthrough

Answer (score 2):

You can try to do this on TF 2 with eager mode on.

> Please notice that you need to use `tf.keras` for everything, including your model, layers, etc. For this to work you can never use `keras` alone, it must be `tf.keras`. This means, for instance, using `tf.keras.layers.Dense`, `tf.keras.models.Sequential`, etc..

```
input_images_tensor = tf.constant(input_images_numpy)
with tf.GradientTape() as g:
    g.watch(input_images_tensor)
    output_tensor = model(input_images_tensor)

gradients = g.gradient(output_tensor, input_images_tensor)
```

If you are going to calculate the gradients more than once with the same tape, you need the tape to be `persistent=True` and delete it manually after you get the gradients. (See details on the link below)

You can get the gradients regarding any "trainable" weight without needing `watch`. If you are going to get gradients with respect to non-trainable tensors (such as the input images), then you must call `g.watch` as above for each of these variables).

More details on `GradientTape`: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape